# Nested routing with state provider in nested navigation

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

[navigation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5EIvx.png)

```
.state('parent', {
                abstract: true,
                url: "/parent",
                templateUrl: "app/components/common/content.html"
    }).state('parent.child', {
                url: "/child",
                templateUrl: "app/components/common/content.html",
                data: { pageTitle: 'Child' } 
    }).state('parent.child.subchild', {
                url: "/child/subchild",
                templateUrl: "sometemplateURl.html",
                data: { pageTitle: 'subchild' } 
            });
```

Not able to access sub child state, Can you help on this what I am doing wrong here  ?

Attached the image for reference of navigation.

---

Answer (score 0):

There are two spelling mistakes in the 2nd/3rd state names ('prarent' vs 'parent'). I would probably suggest having a different template for each state too.